# Why do I get an error when trying to access a model object from a different model in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in my `users/show.html.erb` view, and I am doing this:

```ruby
<div class="feedback_field span7">
  <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
    <div class="poster_id">
      <%= f.hidden_field "poster_id", :value => current_user.id %><br />
    </div>
    <div class="receiver_id">
      <%= f.hidden_field "receiver_id", :value => @user.id %><br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, nil, :maxlength => 250, :class => 'xxlarge' %>
    </div>

    <%= submit_tag "Send", :class => "btn" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

However, the error I keep getting is this:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Any thoughts?

**Edit 1**

When I add `@feedback = Feedback.new` to the show action of my controller, I get a routing error that looks like this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil}):
    7:                 <strong>Share what you think</strong>
    8:             </div>
    9:             <div class="feedback_field span7">
    10:                 <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
    11:                     <div class="poster_id">
    12:                     <%= f.hidden_field "poster_id", :value => current_user.id %><br />
    13:                     </div>
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3843741595115817595_2495618900'
  app/controllers/vanities_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

**Edit 2**

I tried adding the `:url` option, like this: `<%= form_for(@feedback, :url => new_feedback_path(@feedback)) do |f| %>` and got this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"feedbacks"}):
    7:                 <strong>Share what you think</strong>
    8:             </div>
    9:             <div class="feedback_field span7">
    10:                 <%= form_for(@feedback, :url => new_feedback_path(@feedback)) do |f| %>
    11:                     <div class="poster_id">
    12:                     <%= f.hidden_field "poster_id", :value => current_user.id %><br />
    13:                     </div>
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3843741595115817595_2166988680'
  app/controllers/vanities_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

**Edit 3**

Relevant output of `rake routes`:

```
feedbacks GET    /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              POST   /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
 new_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
edit_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
     feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              PUT    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              DELETE /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
```

**Edit 4**

Routes file that corresponds to the `feedback` resources:

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

**Edit 5**

This is what the `Post` action looks like after I use `root_path` in the `form_for`:

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-17 04:19:27 -0500
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0bbhasidfasdf72k2323424=", "feedback"=>{"poster_id"=>"4", "receiver_id"=>"5", "content"=>"Hrmm...this isn't working. How annoying."}, "commit"=>"Send"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (103.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 118ms (Views: 115.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried to put `:url` option to `form_for` block?

Comment: tried it, and put the results in the original question.

Comment: can you please try the :url option with create_feedback_path; if that does not work, could you check your routes using "rake routes"?

Comment: @blackbird07 this is the error I get for `create_feedback_path`: `undefined method 'create_feedback_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001026d7830>:0x000001026d3118>`. Added my rake routes output to the question.

Comment: You probably have routes in place for feedback resource.

Comment: try `form_for :feedback, :url => feedbacks_path`, and in controller `Feedback.new(params[:feedback])`

Comment: @Chirantan Added my routes file info.

Comment: thanks kishie for correcting my mistake - create_feedback_path was kind of silly :) @marcamillion, can you please try this as suggested by kishie?

Comment: just tried @kishie's suggestion, this is the error I get:

`ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks"}):
    7:                 <strong>Share what you think</strong>
    8:             </div>
    9:             <div class="feedback_field span7">
    10:                 <%= form_for :feedback, :url => feedbacks_path do |f| %>`

Comment: then put `root_path` or any working route instead. `:url` is used the form to redirect to a path after submitting

Comment: That did work...as in, I no longer get the error. But when I create the `new` Feedback, the form doesn't work. I have updated the question with the log information of what the `post` action looks like.

Comment: Ah, sure, you should create a new action where new Feedback will be created, create route for it and put this route name to `:url` option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue was related to my routing.

I did eventually figure it out, but I had to do a lot of digging to get there...which led to this other question:

[How do I create a named_route_path for a scoped/nested resource in rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843370/how-do-i-create-a-named-route-path-for-a-scoped-nested-resource-in-rails-3-1)

The answer there solves this issue for me.