# How do I create a named_route_path for a scoped/nested resource in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my route:

```
scope ":username" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

When I do `rake routes`, I get this:

```
    feedbacks GET    /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              POST   /:username/feedbacks(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
 new_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
edit_feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
     feedback GET    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              PUT    /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
              DELETE /:username/feedbacks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"feedbacks"}
```

But when I do feedbacks_url or feedbacks_path I get an routing error like this:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil}
```

From the log file:

```
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (18.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 142ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"feedbacks", :format=>nil}):
    1: <%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
    2:   <% if @feedback.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@feedback.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feedback from being saved:</h2>
  app/views/feedbacks/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_feedbacks__form_html_erb__2195884682603870163_2484875900'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__3889159515317937411_2159438040'
  app/controllers/vanities_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

This is the form partial `feedbacks/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
  <% if @feedback.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@feedback.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feedback from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @feedback.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if current_user %>

       <div class="poster_id">
        <%= f.hidden_field "poster_id", :value => current_user.id %><br />
       </div>
       <div class="receiver_id">
         <%= f.hidden_field "receiver_id", :value => @user.id %><br />
       </div>
       <div class="field">
         <%= f.text_field :content %>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
         <%= f.submit %>
       </div>

   <% end %>


<% end %>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

```
scope ":username" do
```

means that your routes need some info about `:username` to work properly.

You should then add this info in all your links:

```
user_path(user, :username => "joe")
edit_user_path(user, :username => "joe")
...
```

Or you could tell your app the `username` isn't mandatory which seems logic if user isn't created yet. So change your route to:

```
scope "(:username)" do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't `feedback_url(user, @feedback)` also be possible? Given that the route would be expecting the first argument to be the `username`?

Comment: that last change of editing the `routes` file, works perfectly.

Comment: @RyanBigg: I tend to be very explicit but yes, could be cleaner to avoid hash style declarations.